# How to handle signal in foreground process?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

I have doubt, why does we cannot use `kill -s 9 <pid>` or `kill -s 15 <pid>` to kill foreground process? When I am trying to do the same, getting result that process id does not exist meanwhile same is working, when I am using aforementioned commands to kill that program in background.

```
root@onXXXX:~/Documents/Testing_Scripts/NEW_Scrits# sh infinite.sh 20
My process id is 23873 
Counting 20 
Counting 19 
kCounting 18 
ill Counting 17 
-s Counting 16 
15Counting 15 
 Counting 14 
23Counting 13 
8Counting 12 
73Counting 11 

Counting 10 
Counting 9 
Counting 8 
Counting 7 
Counting 6 
Counting 5 
Counting 4 
Counting 3 
Counting 2 
Counting 1 
root@onxXXXX:~/Documents/Testing_Scripts/NEW_Scrits# kill -s 15 23873
-bash: kill: (23873) - No such process
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do. Add the script and correct your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of your outputs, your shell script has been closed and then you are trying to kill it. You can't kill a process which does not exists...

At the same time you can't run a program/command in a shell which another program is running in its foreground.

So what actually is happening here is you run your script, you wait until its job is done, now shell is free to run other programs and now you are trying to kill the already finished process. meanwhile when you send a process in background imitatively you are able to use the shell and you kill the process successfully while it's still running.

Comment: I think I got the point, I was bit confused, after remembering concept of co-routines and their use, I am able to understand it. Thanks for clarification.